# Handles to objects in central registry with automated cleanup

Tags: c++

I have a central repository of objects `Base` which can produce various things. `Base` must keep a pointer to all objects, as a central update method has to iterate through all objects created by the `Base` instance. However, if the last handle to an object is destroyed, there is no need to keep it around any more so `Base` should get somehow informed that it is ok to delete the object now. Manual deletion of objects should be also possible, which would immediately invalidate all handles. Some code to clarify:

```
Base* b = new Base;
auto h0 = b->MakeFoo ();
auto h1 = h0;
b->Delete (h0);
// h1 is invalid here
{
  auto h2 = b->MakeFoo ();
}
// Base::Delete (h2) was called, as the last reference to it died
// shared_ptr/weak_ptr won't work here, as there would be still one
// reference in Base
auto h3 = b->MakeFoo ();
delete b;
// h3 is invalid here, hence shared_ptr is not enough
// weak_ptr would work here
```

Anything ready-to-use out there that I can adopt for this? Performance does not matter too much in this case.

Comment: Hm, you could wrap the "various things" in your own reference-counting class that would call-back `Base` when the count goes down to 1, but that's tricky to implement right.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I'm asking if there is something "ready-to-use" as I'm sure there is some reference counting code out there that could be adopted here.

Comment: auto h0 = b->MakeFoo ();  I thought that 'auto' is a keyword short for automatic and is now obsolete?

Comment: @Marts: It still means "automatic", but "automatic" now means something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this: Your class `Base` outputs `shared_ptr`s through the `Make*` functions, but only stores `weak_ptr`s internally. The update loop can check whether the weak pointer is still valid and remove it if not.

Your final requirement that deleting the base will also kill existing objects is a bit trickier. You could go through the weak pointers in `Base`'s destructor and send a self-destruct signal to all live objects, but that wouldn't stop existing shared pointers.

Comment: The update look might not get called for a long time. And how should the update loop delete the object? All it can do is grab the shared_ptr, but not delete the shared reference counter.

Comment: As long as anyone still holds a shared pointer, you don't want to destroy the object. And if all the shared pointers are gone, your base only contains an invalid weak pointer, which you just erase from your list.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. But I'd still like to notify the handles/shared_ptrs that the base is dead.

Comment: How would that work? If any scope still has a handle, how would it know that the object is dead? You'd have to add a check at every use! You could wrap your objects into a wrapper with a self-destruct and a checked dereference, I suppose.

Comment: Yeah, something like that. All I want is that accessing a (valid) object after the `Base` has been destroyed will always immediately result in an error.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that type of `h1`, `h2`, `h0` is `TYPE*`.

```
class Base {
// ...
  map<TYPE*, int> t_HandleMap;
public:
  TYPE* MakeFoo ()
  {
    TYPE* p = new TYPE;
    t_HandleMap[p] = 0;
    return p;
  }

  static void Delete (Base *&pB, TYPE *pH)
  {
    t_HandleMap.erase(pH);
    if(t_Handlemap.empty())
    {
      delete pB; pB = 0;
    }
  }
  ~Base ()
  {
    for(<iterate through map>)
      delete <pHandle>;
    t_HandleMap.clear();
  }
};
```

**Above is pseudo code just to give idea**. You can enhance on it if it works. The only difference I have made is to make `Delete` a `static`. So now instead of,

```
b->Delete(h1);
```

You have to call

```
Delete(b, h1);
```

This doesn't take care of `h2` case. If you are ok with this approach then, we can try adding some logic to that.

Comment: Why a `map` whose only value is 0? Why not a `set`?

Comment: @Kerrek, you are right. But I haven't use `set` before. can I replace `map` by `set` everywhere in my code?

Comment: `set` and `map` are virtually identical, only that `set` has no mapped type while `map` does. Just say ` t_Handles.insert(p)` instead of `operator[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Someone has to own these objects.  Whoever owns it should hold a shared_ptr.  Everyone else should have a weak_ptr.  If its not clear who owns it, make a service and only let the service own the object.

Comment: The handles own the object, but Base must be informed when the last handle dies and have its own handle in the mean time. Oh and deleting base should invalidate it, as the objects won't work properly if there is no base left.

Comment: They don't own the object if someone can invalidate the object.  That is a big problem in the way you are thinking about this.